# React - frontend component test with Jest

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I've just written test file for my component, at the moment it's very rudimentary.. I'm quite inexperience in written test for frontend. I ran yarn test to this test file and it failed miserably..

Here is the message:

> Unable to find an element with the text: Please review your billing details...

[image]

This is what I have so far for my test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, cleanup, waitForElement } from 'react-testing-library';

// React Router
import { MemoryRouter, Route } from "react-router";

import Show from './Show';


test('it shows the offer', async () => {

  const { getByText } = render(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/booking-requests/20-A1-C2/offer']}>
        <Route
          path="/booking-requests/:booking_request/offer"
          render={props => (
            <Show {...props} />
          )}
        />
      </MemoryRouter>
  );

  //displays the review prompt
  await waitForElement(() => getByText('Please review your billing details, contract preview and Additions for your space. Once you’re happy, accept your offer'));

//displays the confirm button
 await waitForElement(() => getByText('Confirm'));
});
```

and this is the component:

```
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';
import i18n from 'utils/i18n/i18n';
import { Btn } from '@appearhere/bloom';
import css from './Show.css';
import StepContainer from 'components/Layout/DynamicStepContainer/DynamicStepContainer';

const t = i18n.withPrefix('client.apps.offers.show');

const confirmOfferSteps = [
  {
    title: t('title'),
    breadcrumb: t('breadcrumb'),
  },
  {
    title: i18n.t('client.apps.offers.billing_information.title'),
    breadcrumb: i18n.t('client.apps.offers.billing_information.breadcrumb'),
  },
  {
    title: i18n.t('client.apps.offers.confirm_pay.title'),
    breadcrumb: i18n.t('client.apps.offers.confirm_pay.breadcrumb'),
  },
];

class Show extends React.Component<Props> {
  steps = confirmOfferSteps;

  renderCtaButton = (): React.Element<'Btn'> => {
    const cta = t('cta');

    return <Btn className={css.button} context='primary'>
      {cta}
    </Btn>
  };

  renderLeftContent = ({ isMobile }: { isMobile: boolean }): React.Element<'div'> => (
    <div>
      <p>{t('blurb')}</p>

      {!isMobile && this.renderCtaButton()}
    </div>
  );

  renderRightContent = () => {
    return <div>Right content</div>;
  };

  render() {
    const ctaButton = this.renderCtaButton();

    return (
      <StepContainer
      steps={this.steps}
      currentStep={1}
      ctaButton={ctaButton}
      leftContent={this.renderLeftContent}
      rightContent={this.renderRightContent}
      footer={ctaButton}
    />
    );
  }
}

export default Show;
```

what am I missing? Suggestions what else to add to my test file would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where does it fail? Is there an error message?

Comment: @TonyAbrams It say that it's Unable to find an element with the text: Please review your billing details...

Comment: do console.log on entire rendered element and see if it really renders the item that you are looking for. In ideal test you should refrain from hardcoded value rather you should import the text or call the same function that you called inside your main component to render/get text and use that here. in your case it may be this sting `client.apps.offers.billing_information.breadcrumb`

Comment: @Rikin right okay I can try that. What else should I add to my test in order to run a full coverage on everything that is on the component?